# TweetInvi Tweets to string or Json

Tags: c#, json, twitter, ssis

I'm certainly not well experienced when it comes to c# but require it odd time SSIS, I'm trying to use TweetInvi to extract a timeline and then insert that time line data into a string file into a database to be processed.  but I'm struggling...please help or point me in a direction of help.

here is what I've got

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Auth.SetApplicationOnlyCredentials("XxxxxxxxXXXxxxXXX", "XXxxxXXX");

        MessageBox.Show("started");

        var usertimelinetweets = Timeline.GetUserTimeline("Testr",1);



        this.Close();
```

Clearly at the most basic point, but I simple am in the dark here.

Comment: Any success with the solution I provided?

Comment: Its better than before but I'm now getting an error on the line


`var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tweets.Select(x => x.TweetDTO));`
Saying that it can't be null, Which I presuming is due to the authorization not the coding

Comment: Well it means that either `tweets` or `TweetDTO` is null. The first case can happen if you effectively have a problem with your authentication. You have to check if you effectively get back data from `Timeline.GetHomeTimeline`

Comment: cool I'll take a look at that.

Comment: When I've look the tweets variable is null, therefore if must be a problem with my authentication, however in the
`Auth.SetApplicationOnlyCredentials("xxxxXXXxxx", "xxxXXXxxx");` 
I've entered the correct consumerkey and secret so I'm a little confused, I might try creating some fresh keys and see what happens.

Comment: For some reason `Timeline.GetUserTimeline` requires User Authentication as noted in the documentation : https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline

Comment: You can use `Auth.SetUserCredentials` and get the credentials for your account directly at apps.twitter.com

Comment: Excellent it working...or should I say its not null, thanks for all your help!

Comment: Don't forget to mark the solution as answered so that people can find the answer if they experience the same problem. I will update the answer to include the information about `UserTimeline` authentication requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is actually quite simple. Tweetinvi is automatically installed with Newtonsoft.Json.NET.

You can use Tweetinvi 1.0 support for serialization as followed :

```
var tweets = Timeline.GetHomeTimeline();

// Store 1 array
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tweets.Select(x => x.TweetDTO));

// Or iterate
foreach (var tweet in tweets)
{
    var tweetjson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tweet.TweetDTO);
}
```

You can learn more in the documentation: https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki/Serialization-and-Deserialization

Note that for some reason Timeline.GetUserTimeline requires User Authentication as noted in the documentation : https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline.

To do that use `Auth.SetUserCredentials` as opposed to `Auth.SetApplicationOnlyCredentials`.